# How to store files in firebase using node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a small assignment where I will have a URL to a document or a file like google drive link or dropbox link.

I have to use this link to store that file or doc in firebase using nodejs. How should i start?

Little head's up might help. What should i use? Please help I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for using the admin SDK is mostly covered in [GCP documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/latest/storage/bucket).

Here's a snippet of code that shows how you could upload a image directly to Cloud Storage if you have a URL for it. Any public link works, whether it's shared from Dropbox or somewhere else on the internet.

**Edit 2020-06-01** The option to upload directly from URL was dropped in v2.0 of the SDK (4 September 2018): https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/releases/tag/v2.0.0

```
const fileUrl = 'https://www.dropbox.com/some/file/download/link.jpg';
const opts = {
  destination: 'path/to/file.jpg',
  metadata: {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg'
  }
};

firebase.storage().bucket().upload(fileUrl, opts);
```

This example is using the default bucket in your application and the `opts` object provides file upload options for the API call.

- `destination` is the path that your file will be uploaded to in Google Cloud Storage
- `metadata` should describe the file that you're uploading ([see more examples here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/Bucket#upload))

  - `contentType` is the file [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) that you are uploading

Comment: Any idea why when I'm running it from my local `firebase serve` is changing the path to my local directory? (eg. C:\Documents\Project\cloud-functions\functions\https:\myimageurl.com)
When I deploy it to Firebase Functions it's loading the right url but with an error that there isn't such file or directory.

Comment: I think I'd need a bit more information on how you've implemented and configured it. Could you post it as a new question with full context and then I can have a look at it.

Comment: I just tested this and no you can't just give it a url and have it uploaded directly from web to fb storage.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I looked it up and this functionality was dropped in [v2.0 of the storage SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/releases/tag/v2.0.0). I see that my answer was actually already outdated at the time of writing. I'll update the answer to clarify