# How to store an image on Firebase Storage from a Cloud functions

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I would like to be able to add security rules on Firebase Storage to control and prevent image import from the application. For that I would like to be able to send an image or audio file to a Cloud Functions, so that it takes care of the uploads itself, and not from the Front part.

My question is therefore the following: Knowing that we can already store an image directly from a Flutter application, is it possible to do the same thing but from a Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within server-side environments such as Cloud Functions, you can use the Firebase Admin SDK to interact with Cloud Storage. In this case you'll end up using a [pre-initialized version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.storage.md#firebase-adminstorage_module) of the [Node.js SDK for Cloud Storage](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage).

With that knowledge we can search for [Node.js SDK for Cloud Storage upload file](https://www.google.com/search?q=Node.js+SDK+for+Cloud+Storage+upload+file), which leads to:

- [How to store files in firebase using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53969468/how-to-store-files-in-firebase-using-node-js) for uploading files
- [Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase) for getting a signed URL